# Who is this chess player photographed on Sputnik Mediabank #972762?

Tags: famous-players, identify-this

Can someone identify the chess player in this photo?

[image]

The source of the photograph is [Sputnik Mediabank #972762](https://sputnikmediabank.com/media/972762.html), where the caption says:

> International chess Grandmaster Mikhail Tal watching a game.

However, the player (man sitting at the board) doesn't look like Tal.

Comment: I notice that caption says it's Tal watching the game, so I'm wonder if the man standing on the right is in fact Tal. However, with only his chin being clearly in the image, it's hard to tell, and its really not clear why the photo would be labeled as being of him and not Polugaevsky who seems to be actually playing the game, as identified below.

Comment: FWIW, there are other photos by the same photographer. [#972761](https://sputnikmediabank.com/media/972761.html) mentioned "*International Grandmaster Mikhail Tal watches a game at the Moscow Interzonal Chess Tournament.*"

Comment: @wim: You might note that you don't believe the caption in the photo (i.e. that it's a picture of Tal) and why.

Comment: @GreenMatt Done. Perhaps the original photo has been cropped too aggressively.

Comment: @wim: Thanks. I suspect RisingZan's explanation is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [Lev Polugaevsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lev_Polugaevsky). Here's a reference pic of old Polugaevsky.

[image]

Despite the caption from the source, it's not Mikhail Tal. He did indeed have only 3 fingers on his right hand.